Equivalent of dpkg-statoverride for RPM-based distros
If you just chmod a file installed by a package (e.g., chmod 4750 /usr/bin/foo), future updates to the package can wipe out your change. On deb-based distros like Debian and Ubuntu, dpkg-statoverride lets you tell the package manager about your change so that it will persist through updates (e.g., dpkg-statoverride --add root foo 4750 /usr/bin/foo). How do I accomplish the same thing on RPM-based distros like Fedora and RHEL?

Just as https://superuser.com/questions/158047/overriding-installed-file-directory-permissions-owners, I'd not be aware of anything like that for RPM-based distros.
You could go for Fedora Silverblue and try to make an overlay that just changes that one file, but I don't think you could affect the mode only.
Making binary files from a package unreadable seems a bit questionable to me, anyways: the user that can't read the file can still get that same file from a prefix extraction of the same package, and just execute that. Sounds to me like you'd rather put these users' processes (or the users that need to run that program) into their own filesystem namespace and not interact with the rest of the system altogether.

I don't really care about making binary files unreadable. I just want to make it non-executable by users not in a particular group. And that does have value even though its contents are publicly known, since it's setuid.

oh! That is understandable, but still, I don't think RPM-based distros have anything for that, other than building your own version of the package containing that file, which should be identical (but for the permissions) and conflict with the upstream package.
